# Auto Increment HTML class/ID to differentiate between divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently working on an application where the user gets a list a bunch of divs with details on them, there are also hidden details in each div that can be toggled by the user. The issue is that when you click on "details" for one box it toggles the class on all boxes rather than just within the one that was clicked. I was looking for an answer to this issue and have come up with trying to auto-increment the ID's/Class so that each box that is created will have a unique identifier. I need to make it so that the "extra-details" is only opened in relation to the card "details" is clicked on. Thank you in advance for any help.

My Code

```js
$(".card-details").on("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(".extra-details").toggleClass("hidden");
        });
```

```css
h4 {
 padding:10px 0 0 5px;
 font-size:18px;
 font-weight:bold;
}
.card {
    border:none;
    box-shadow:2px 2px 5px rgba(201,201,201, .5);
    padding:5px;
    margin:5px;
    max-width:350px;
    background:transparent;
    border:1px solid #efefef;
    font-size:12px;
}
hr {
    border:1px solid #efefef;
    width:100%;
    margin-top:0;
}
.card-head {
    color:#005ABB;
}
.card-container{
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-left:5px;
}
.card-info {
    margin-left:20px;
    background:transparent !important;
}
.card-details {
    color:#005ABB;
    margin-left:85%;
}
.card-details:hover {
    text-decoration:underline;
    color:#F9A51B;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.hidden{
    display:none !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row card-container">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 card">
                            <h4 class="card-head">20 Foot Titan Chassis</h4>
                            <hr>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 pull-left card-info">
                                    Equipment Type
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 pull-left card-info">
                                    Available Quantity
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 pull-left card-info">
                                    Selected Quantity
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 card-details">
                                Details
                            </div>
                            <div class="row extra-details hidden">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 card-info">
                                    Address: Test Address
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-12 card-info">
                                    Hours of Operation: Weekdays 9AM - 5PM
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 card">
                            <h4 class="card-head">20 Foot Titan Chassis</h4>
                            <hr>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 pull-left card-info">
                                    Equipment Type
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 pull-left card-info">
                                    Available Quantity
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 pull-left card-info">
                                    Selected Quantity
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 card-details">
                                Details
                            </div>
                            <div class="row extra-details hidden">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 card-info">
                                    Address: Test Address
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-12 card-info">
                                    Hours of Operation: Weekdays 9AM - 5PM
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 card">
                            <h4 class="card-head">20 Foot Titan Chassis</h4>
                            <hr>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 pull-left card-info">
                                    Equipment Type
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 pull-left card-info">
                                    Available Quantity
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 pull-left card-info">
                                    Selected Quantity
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 card-details">
                                Details
                            </div>
                            <div class="row extra-details hidden">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 card-info">
                                    Address: Test Address
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-12 card-info">
                                    Hours of Operation: Weekdays 9AM - 5PM
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 card">
                            <h4 class="card-head">20 Foot Titan Chassis</h4>
                            <hr>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 pull-left card-info">
                                    Equipment Type
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 pull-left card-info">
                                    Available Quantity
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 pull-left card-info">
                                    Selected Quantity
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 card-details">
                                Details
                            </div>
                            <div class="row extra-details hidden">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 card-info">
                                    Address: Test Address
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-12 card-info">
                                    Hours of Operation: Weekdays 9AM - 5PM
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 card">
                            <h4 class="card-head">20 Foot Titan Chassis</h4>
                            <hr>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 pull-left card-info">
                                    Equipment Type
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 pull-left card-info">
                                    Available Quantity
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 pull-left card-info">
                                    Selected Quantity
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 card-details">
                                Details
                            </div>
                            <div class="row extra-details hidden">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 card-info">
                                    Address: Test Address
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-12 card-info">
                                    Hours of Operation: Weekdays 9AM - 5PM
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 card">
                            <h4 class="card-head">20 Foot Titan Chassis</h4>
                            <hr>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 pull-left card-info">
                                    Equipment Type
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 pull-left card-info">
                                    Available Quantity
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 pull-left card-info">
                                    Selected Quantity
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 card-details">
                                Details
                            </div>
                            <div class="row extra-details hidden">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 card-info">
                                    Address: Test Address
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-12 card-info">
                                    Hours of Operation: Weekdays 9AM - 5PM
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Change `$(".extra-details").toggleClass("hidden");` to `$(this).find(".extra-details").toggleClass("hidden");`

Comment: @Acidic needed to be $(this).siblings(".extra-details").toggleClass("hidden"); since it was a sibling. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: yep or my other answer I posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$(".card-details").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).siblings(".extra-details").toggleClass("hidden");
});
```

Answer (score 5):

`$(this).siblings('.extra-details').toggleClass('hidden')` will achieve what you want.

Also note, your 'details' element is not actually a link, only styled like one, so you don't need the `e.preventDefault()` line.

Answer (score 1):

**This works for me.**

I just changed the javascript code as shown below.

```js
$(".card-details").click(function() {
    $(this).closest(".card").find(".extra-details").toggleClass("hidden");
});
```

```css
h4 {
 padding:10px 0 0 5px;
 font-size:18px;
 font-weight:bold;
}
.card {
    border:none;
    box-shadow:2px 2px 5px rgba(201,201,201, .5);
    padding:5px;
    margin:5px;
    max-width:350px;
    background:transparent;
    border:1px solid #efefef;
    font-size:12px;
}
hr {
    border:1px solid #efefef;
    width:100%;
    margin-top:0;
}
.card-head {
    color:#005ABB;
}
.card-container{
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-left:5px;
}
.card-info {
    margin-left:20px;
    background:transparent !important;
}
.card-details {
    color:#005ABB;
    margin-left:85%;
}
.card-details:hover {
    text-decoration:underline;
    color:#F9A51B;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.hidden{
    display:none !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row card-container">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 card">
                            <h4 class="card-head">20 Foot Titan Chassis</h4>
                            <hr>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 pull-left card-info">
                                    Equipment Type
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 pull-left card-info">
                                    Available Quantity
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 pull-left card-info">
                                    Selected Quantity
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 card-details">
                                Details
                            </div>
                            <div class="row extra-details hidden">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 card-info">
                                    Address: Test Address
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-12 card-info">
                                    Hours of Operation: Weekdays 9AM - 5PM
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 card">
                            <h4 class="card-head">20 Foot Titan Chassis</h4>
                            <hr>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 pull-left card-info">
                                    Equipment Type
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 pull-left card-info">
                                    Available Quantity
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 pull-left card-info">
                                    Selected Quantity
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 card-details">
                                Details
                            </div>
                            <div class="row extra-details hidden">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 card-info">
                                    Address: Test Address
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-12 card-info">
                                    Hours of Operation: Weekdays 9AM - 5PM
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 card">
                            <h4 class="card-head">20 Foot Titan Chassis</h4>
                            <hr>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 pull-left card-info">
                                    Equipment Type
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 pull-left card-info">
                                    Available Quantity
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 pull-left card-info">
                                    Selected Quantity
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 card-details">
                                Details
                            </div>
                            <div class="row extra-details hidden">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 card-info">
                                    Address: Test Address
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-12 card-info">
                                    Hours of Operation: Weekdays 9AM - 5PM
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 card">
                            <h4 class="card-head">20 Foot Titan Chassis</h4>
                            <hr>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 pull-left card-info">
                                    Equipment Type
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 pull-left card-info">
                                    Available Quantity
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 pull-left card-info">
                                    Selected Quantity
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 card-details">
                                Details
                            </div>
                            <div class="row extra-details hidden">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 card-info">
                                    Address: Test Address
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-12 card-info">
                                    Hours of Operation: Weekdays 9AM - 5PM
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 card">
                            <h4 class="card-head">20 Foot Titan Chassis</h4>
                            <hr>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 pull-left card-info">
                                    Equipment Type
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 pull-left card-info">
                                    Available Quantity
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 pull-left card-info">
                                    Selected Quantity
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 card-details">
                                Details
                            </div>
                            <div class="row extra-details hidden">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 card-info">
                                    Address: Test Address
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-12 card-info">
                                    Hours of Operation: Weekdays 9AM - 5PM
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 card">
                            <h4 class="card-head">20 Foot Titan Chassis</h4>
                            <hr>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 pull-left card-info">
                                    Equipment Type
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 pull-left card-info">
                                    Available Quantity
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 pull-left card-info">
                                    Selected Quantity
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 card-details">
                                Details
                            </div>
                            <div class="row extra-details hidden">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 card-info">
                                    Address: Test Address
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-12 card-info">
                                    Hours of Operation: Weekdays 9AM - 5PM
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```